# Node-Crawler - How to show the normal characters data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

I'm trying to get some data from a website containing html with node.js. However, the response is garbled, such as ��ӭǰ���Ա���ʵ�����̣�ѡ��Apple.

Could anyone tell me how can I do to solve that??

Thank you very much!

I have tried as below.

website url [enter link description here](https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a220m.1000858.1000725.7.69c174a7N7YQzY&id=560257961625&areaId=440100&user_id=1917047079&cat_id=2&is_b=1&rn=32724d2b3beca5dba07306927feddd0e&sku_properties=10004:709990523)

```
const urlLib = require('url');
const dataLib = require('./data');

dataLib.getUrl(website url,(buffer)=>{
console.log('done',buffer.toString('utf-8'));
 },()=>{
  console.log('error')
})
```

Here is the data.js

```
const urlLib = require('url');

exports.getUrl = function(sUrl, success, error) {

_req(sUrl);

function _req(sUrl){


let obj = urlLib.parse(sUrl);
let mod = null;
if (obj.protocol == 'http:') {
  mod = require('http')
  } else {
  mod = require('https')
}

let req = mod.request({
  hostname: obj.hostname,
  path: obj.path
}, res => {
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    let arr = [];
    res.on('data', (buffer) => {
      arr.push(buffer)
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
      let b = Buffer.concat(arr)
      success && success(b)
    })

  } else if (res.statusCode == 301 || res.statusCode == 302) {
    _req(res.headers['location'])  
  } else {
    console.log(res.statusCode)
    error && error();
  }

 })

  req.on('error', (err) => { 
    console.log( err)
    error && error(err)
  })

 req.end()
 }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the domain ?

Comment: I meant the website's url. I didn't notice you already posted it in your qusetion, apologies.

Comment: no worries :) @Evyatar Meged

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're getting the data but you are not able to decode to it. This is typically the case with garbled characters like ��ӭǰ���Ա���ʵ�����̣�ѡ��.

I notice you are specifying `'utf-8'` as the encoding in [`buf.toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end). It should be `'utf8'` (without hyphen).

Comment: I have tried 'utf8' with no hyphen... but it didn't work... : (